# Converting HTML string to object without using DOM

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is my string: `Hi there! This is <b>bold</b>. This is <i>italic</i> and this is <u>underlined</u>.`

My desired array of objects:

```
result = [
    { style: 'none', text: 'Hi there! This is ' },
    { style: 'b', text: 'bold' },
    { style: 'none', text: '. This is ' },
    { style: 'i', text: 'italic' },
    { style: 'none', text: ' and this is ' },
    { style: 'u', text: 'underlined' },
    { style: 'none', text: '.' },
]
```

This must be immutable.

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all to write code to accomplish this yourself yet? Why can't you use DOM, it would be far easier than reinventing the wheel, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to put effort into at least *attempting* to solve your own problems before asking the internet for help... However, I was interested in creating a solution for this particular problem so I did.

First, you need to use regex to split up your HTML so it's easier to decipher each text's style. Here's the regex I used: `/(<[A-z]*>.+?<\/[A-z]*>)/`. Splitting with this particular regex turns this:

`Hi there! This is <b>bold</b>. This is <i>italic</i> and this is <u>underlined</u>.`

into this:

```
["Hi there! This is ", "<b>bold</b>", ". This is ", "<i>italic</i>", " and this is ", "<u>underlined</u>", "."]
```

Now that we've got each portion of text separated based on whether or not it's surrounded by HTML tags, we can easily decipher which portions of a particular input have style.

Since you stated the implementation must be immutable, I opted to use `Array.prototype.reduce`. I reduce the array created above into a singular results object containing each portion of a text's style and text by calling the function `extractStyle` on each array index.

The `extractStyle` function uses the following regex `/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/.+?>/` to split the supplied text by its DOM tags. Here's the result of this regex on different values in the array created above with the initial regex:

```
console.log('<b>bold</b>'.split(/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/.+?>/)); // ["", "b", "bold", ""]
console.log('Hi there! This is '.split(/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/.+?>/)); // ["Hi there! This is "]
```

As you can see, text surrounded by DOM elements turns into an array with 4 indexes, index position 1 being the style, and index position 2 being the text, while regular text is simply an array with a length of 1.

Now, all I have to do with the array is see if it's of length 4 or 1. If it's of length 1, I return an object with `style: 'none'` and `text: array[0]`. If it's of length 4, then I return `style: array[1]` and `text: array[2]`.

After all of that this:

`Hi there! This is <b>bold</b>. This is <i>italic</i> and this is <u>underlined</u>.`

Becomes:

```
[
  {
    "style": "none",
    "text": "Hi there! This is "
  },
  {
    "style": "b",
    "text": "bold"
  },
  {
    "style": "none",
    "text": ". This is "
  },
  {
    "style": "i",
    "text": "italic"
  },
  {
    "style": "none",
    "text": " and this is "
  },
  {
    "style": "u",
    "text": "underlined"
  },
  {
    "style": "none",
    "text": "."
  }
]
```

And lastly, here's the snippet:

```js
const html = 'Hi there! This is <b>bold</b>. This is <i>italic</i> and this is <u>underlined</u>.'
const components = html.split(/(<[A-z]*>.+?<\/[A-z]*>)/);
const styleDefinition = components.reduce((accumulator, dom) => {
  accumulator.push(extractStyle(dom));
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(styleDefinition);

function extractStyle(dom) {
  const domComponents = dom.split(/<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/.+?>/);
  const isStyled = domComponents.length === 4;
  return {
    style: isStyled ? domComponents[1] : 'none',
    text: isStyled ? domComponents[2] : domComponents[0]
  };
}
```

**NOTE:** All I ask is that you read this post in its entirety so you at least learn how to implement a solution to a similar problem in the future. That way, you can attempt to solve your problems on your own without needed to ask the internet to implement solutions for you.

Comment: Better: use a HTML parsing library.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Yeah that'd be better for sure but he wanted an implementation for parsing deprecated DOM elements within a string into a specific format for some reason.